# How to generate a mesh file with extracting nodes and elements

Tags: mesh

I need to generate a mesh file, where I need to extract the following information :

- X Y and Z coordinates of each node + the nodetags
- list of all the elements + elementtags

I would like to give each edge(the elements and the nodes of the edges) of my domain an index, in order to use it in my code for the management of BC, IC and parameters...)

Is there any preexisting code that would help me to do that ?

I tried `gmsh`, but I can't really understand the syntax of the `.msh` file, which is different from the explanation they propose in : [9.1 MSH file format](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-file-format)

Answer (score 0):

I've created [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) for this purpose. Here's how to write a file:

```py
points = numpy.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ])
cells = {
    "triangle": numpy.array([
        [0, 1, 2]
        ])
    }
meshio.write_points_cells(
    "foo.vtk",
    points,
    cells,
    # Optionally provide extra data on points, cells, etc.
    # point_data=point_data,
    # cell_data=cell_data,
    # field_data=field_data
    )
```

Many different formats are supported.